# Visa cancellation by employer

Tags: visas, usa, thailand

I work in Thailand, can my employer by any means cancel my USA visa? Does the employer have that right ?

Visa on the passport of an employee is the property of an employee or employer ?

Comment: Your employer can contact the US Embassy and withdraw any support they provided for your visa application.  But only the US government can cancel your visa.  The visa is 'property' of the US government.

Comment: It means the employer is having the right ? They provided only a letter that states that i need to attend the meeting there.Does this matter?

Comment: Does visa's get cancel this way?A general idea that does the US embassy cancel the visa if such case happens??

Comment: If the reason given for your visa is the meeting and the company verified this, then you travel for other reasons and get found out, then that becomes a black mark against the company for future visa requests for staff.

Comment: The decision to cancel or not lays entirely in the hands of the US.  They will not cancel simply because your boss asks, rather they will look at the whole picture then decide.

Comment: If the purpose of your travel to the USA was a business meeting, and this is the basis upon which the visa was issued, and that meeting is now not going to take place - what is your purpose of traveling to the USA, and what would you say to the immigration agent at the airport? Would you lie & risk deportation? My first USA visa had a specific notation listed on it with the name of the company I was visiting...

Comment: @Tom on the other hand, the traveler could approach the consulate and says "the meeting for which I applied for this visa has been cancelled, but now I would like to go to the US for a different reason, do I need to apply for a new visa?" The consulate might say, "no, use the visa you have," in which case there would be no threat of a black mark.

Comment: @phoog - oh, if only the US Embassy in Thailand was so generous. :(

Comment: @Tom well it would depend a bit on the kind of visa issued, wouldn't it? We don't know what kind it is. If it is a multiple-entry B-1/B-2 visa they shouldn't require a new application.  Granted, that may be unlikely. Axe, what kind of visa is it?

Comment: I have a B1/B2 visa,what are the possibilities?

Comment: @axe how long is it valid for, and for how many entries?

Comment: @axe this is going beyond the scope of your initial question, to which the answer is no. If you want to ask about the conditions under which you can use your visa, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

No.

The visa is the property of the issuing government, just like your passport is the property of the government that issued it.

Only the issuing government/state/authority has the power to revoke or invalidate visas.

Your employer can make a *request*, but that is about it.

Furthermore, a visa is not a guarantee of entry. It is just a permit to request entry at a border. So even if you have a visa, there is no guarantee you will be allowed to enter on it, especially (as it seems from the comments) the circumstances against which the visa was issued have changed substantially.